Behavior of an ideal spring
Let's pull on an ideal spring from both sides with force $F$. According to Hooke's law, the extension of the spring is $x=F/k$. But why would the spring extend at all? I mean, the net force on the spring is zero so it shouldn’t extend, right?

One force just holds the spring, like it would be on a hook, the other extends it, Remember every force has an oppsit force!

suppose i pull on friend 1 with force F.But he's also being pulled by friend 2 with force F.He's not going to move.So why would the spring move?

His arms would also be extended (or pulled out) ? The spring does not move, it is extended

oh,right.But for some reason it doesnt make sense to me.(If the net force is zero,there will be no acceleration,im stuck at this sentence.I am thinking,not net force,no movement)

@dxdydz Your friend 1 wouldn't move but surely he/she is experiencing internal mechanical stress which, if your friend were elastic like a sprinng, would result in stretching your friend.

This is a poor question. When learning an equation in physics, you need to know what each variable means. Did you attempt to understand what $F$ represents? It is the tension in the spring and not the net force on it. The net force is always zero for massless springs.

Related : Spring force on both sides of spring.


... the net force on the spring is zero..so it shouldn’t extend ...

No. If the net force on the spring is zero then its centre of mass remains at rest by Newton's First Law. However, this does not prevent it extending (or contracting) as long as it does so equally on each side of its centre of mass.
In fact, even a solid bar will extend very slightly if we exert equal and opposite forces on each end of it - perfectly rigid bodies are a theoretical abstraction and do not exist in the real world. The only difference with a spring is that amount of extension is larger. In the language of materials science, we say that a spring has a much smaller Young's modulus than a solid bar.

Are you suggesting the position of the COM doesn't change when the force is applied to the spring?

@BobD If the net force on the spring is always zero then its COM must remain at rest. Conversely, if the spring's COM goes from being at rest to not being at rest (if, for example, one end of the spring is fixed) then there must be a period of time, no matter how short, when the net force on the spring is not zero in order to accelerate the COM. Of course, if we assume a light spring, then we can make this period as short as we like.

The COM begins and ends at rest.


I mean, the net force on the spring is zero..so it shouldn’t
extend,right?

A net force of zero on an object simply means the object will not undergo acceleration. It doesn't means the object is not subjected to internal stresses that may result in strain (compression or expansion). Think of a column resting on the ground at the bottom and supporting a structure (weight) on top. The net force on the column is zero (it does not accelerate), yet the column is subjected to internal compressive stress resulting in compressive strain, albeit small. It is, in effect, a very stiff spring.
Now consider a horizontally oriented spring attached to a wall. See FIG A. The spring is initially relaxed. We apply a gradually increasing horizontal force to the free end until we reach the desired maximum applied force. That force will equal the spring restoring force. See FIG B. The spring is now in equilibrium.
A free body diagram (See FIG C) of the spring shows that the applied force is equal to the reaction force of the fixed wall, for equilibrium of the spring. The two equal forces represent the tension in the spring.
In the process of extending the spring the net work done on the spring is zero. The applied force does positive work of $+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ while the work done by the spring restoring force, the direction of which is opposite the direction of the displacement, does an equal amount of negative work of $-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. In effect the spring takes the energy supplied by the applied force and stores it as elastic potential energy in the spring.
Hope this helps.


The net force on the spring is indeed zero which means that it is at rest (or moving with constant velocity).
With the unextended spring the molecules which comprise the spring have an equilibrium spacing and no net force on each of the molecules.
Now consider what happens when external forces are applied to the "end" molecules of a spring.
Those "end$ molecules have a net force on them pulling them away from the "bulk" of the spring and the separation of those "end" molecules from their nearest neighbours in the "bulk" of the spring increases.
This in turn means that there is now attractive forces on the "end" molecules due adjacent molecules in the "bulk" of the spring.
The new increased equilibrium separation of the molecules is when the applied external forces are equal in magnitude to the attractive forces between the molecules with increased separation.
Thus the external forces applied to the ends of the spring have increased the molecular separation, ie the spring has been stretched.


I mean,the net force on the spring is zero..so it shouldn’t
extend,right?

What we can conclude is that, as the net force on the spring is zero it doesn't accelerate.
Elastic deformation is the standard way to measure  force. Suppose the cable joins the hand of an athlete and a steel mass. If he pulls the cable with the weight fixed somewhere, a strain gage in the cable measures a small deformation and, using the elastic properties of the material, the force. We can imagine a spring between the weight and the wall where it is attached. It will indicate another force, proportional to the displacement, equal and opposite to the first. The net force on the weight is zero and there is no acceleration.
When the athlete turns the weight in a circle to throw it, the strain gage also indicates a force, but now it is the net force, and there is also a (centripetal) acceleration.


Let's pull on an ideal spring from both sides with force $F$.
According to Hooke's law, the extension of the spring is $x=F/k$. But
why would the spring extend at all? I mean, the net force on the
spring is zero so it shouldn’t extend, right?

The trick to analysing this situation is to treat the two halves of the spring as two smaller springs in their own right. The original centre does not move and acts like an immovable wall. Examining the right half, the right end extends while its other end (the original middle) remains stationary. The half spring extends until the reaction force matches the force on the right and then comes to rest in its extended position. The same is going on on the left.
For a numerical example, let's say the original spring is $1 \ \text{m}$ long and the spring constant is $40$, and we apply a force on $8 \ \text{N}$ to one end. If one end of this spring is fixed, the other end will extend by $x = F/k = 8/40 = 0.2 \ \text{m}$. At equilibrium, there will be a force of $8 \ \text{N}$ at the free end and a reaction force of $8 \ \text{N}$ at the wall. The situation is essentially the same when the spring is pulled apart by a force of $8 \ \text{N}$ at both ends. The only difference is that the reference point for the displacement changes from the fixed end to the centre. Each half spring extends by $0.1 \ \text{m}$ in opposite directions from the centre.
Just for confirmation, the spring constant $k$ is inversely proportional to the length of the spring, so $k \propto E/L$, where $E$ is the elastic modulus. For the half spring, $k$ is twice the original spring constant, so the extension of a half spring on either side is half that of the original spring.
